# Why in my phpbb forum no attacment images displayed?

Tags: phpbb

Would you, please, help me to understand, why there is no images displayed in my forum as attachments?

phpBB is 3.0.14.

For example, you have a topic and would like to leave a message in this topic. You create a message, and in this message you would like to attach *.jpg image. You upload image. But when message is published in the topic the image is not visible, it shows in rectangle with the name of the image. The link to the image looks like this myurl/forum/download/file.php?id=56&mode=view. When you click on the image as an attachment, you see the error (in Firefox, for example) "The image "myurl/forum/download/file.php?id=56"" cannot be displayed, because has errors.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfT35.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) We can not answer without more context elements. (Phpbb version, log errors, what do you mean exactly by no images displayed (wrong url, image not loaded but goog href...)

Comment: phpBB is 3.0.14. For example, you have a topic and would like to leave a message in this topic. You create a message, and in this message you would like to attach *.jpg image. You upload image. But when message is published in the topic the image is not visible, it shows in rectangle with the name of the image. The link to the image looks like this myurl/forum/download/file.php?id=56&mode=view. When you click on the image as an attachment, you see the error (in Firefox, for example) "The image "myurl/forum/download/file.php?id=56"" cannot be displayed, because has errors.

Comment: You could provide us your php error log file. Otherwise, open the image in text editor, I think you'll find a warning from php there. I have to guess, I'd go for Headers already sent :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. The issue was in my functions.php file in wordpress theme. There was `?> <?php` elements within the file, so functions.php was separated by two php sections. When I delete it ("`?> <?php` ") in the middle of my file, images start working correctly! Thank you!